# django-environ DATABASE_URL format

Tags: python, django

I am using django-environ in my project alongside with postgresql. I have been searching through the docs and found the format for DATABASE_URL to be like this:

DATABASE_URL=psql://user:password:port@database_url/db_name

However, by doing so the output of env.db('DATABASE_URL') is

> {'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': 'user', 'PORT': password, 'NAME': '', 'USER': '', 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'}

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `port` in the wrong place in your URL. It's supposed to come after after the hostname:

```
DATABASE_URL=psql://user:password@host:port/database
```